# how to encrypt on sqlite database in flutter application

Tags: flutter, encryption, mobile, sqflite, sqlcipher-android

I am using flutter mobile framework .Need to encrypt files in database using sqflite_sqlcipher package. can anyone help me out with a sample program?

Comment: Did you ever get to use this package? I too would love to see a sample app.